# workaround for ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel with CAST MULTISET

Tags: oracle, function, exception, plsql, multiset

The call to TEST_FUNCTION below fails with "ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel". A workaround is presented in TEST_FUNCTION2. I boiled down the code as my actual function is far more complex. Tested on Oracle 11G.  Anyone have any idea why the first function fails?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "EMPLOYEE" AS OBJECT
(
    employee_id  NUMBER(38),
    hire_date    DATE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "EMPLOYEE_TABLE" AS TABLE OF EMPLOYEE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION RETURN EMPLOYEE_TABLE IS

table1        EMPLOYEE_TABLE;
table2        EMPLOYEE_TABLE;
return_table  EMPLOYEE_TABLE;
BEGIN

SELECT CAST(MULTISET
(
    SELECT user_id, created FROM all_users
    WHERE LOWER(username) < 'm'
) AS EMPLOYEE_TABLE)
INTO table1 FROM dual;

SELECT CAST(MULTISET
(
    SELECT user_id, created FROM all_users
    WHERE LOWER(username) >= 'm'
) AS EMPLOYEE_TABLE)
INTO table2 FROM dual;

SELECT CAST(MULTISET
(    
    SELECT employee_id, hire_date
      FROM TABLE(table1)
    UNION
    SELECT employee_id, hire_date
      FROM TABLE(table2)
) AS EMPLOYEE_TABLE)
INTO return_table FROM dual;

RETURN return_table;

END TEST_FUNCTION;



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION2 RETURN EMPLOYEE_TABLE IS

table1        EMPLOYEE_TABLE;
table2        EMPLOYEE_TABLE;
return_table  EMPLOYEE_TABLE;
BEGIN

SELECT CAST(MULTISET
(
    SELECT user_id, created FROM all_users
    WHERE LOWER(username) < 'm'
) AS EMPLOYEE_TABLE)
INTO table1 FROM dual;

SELECT CAST(MULTISET
(
    SELECT user_id, created FROM all_users
    WHERE LOWER(username) >= 'm'
) AS EMPLOYEE_TABLE)
INTO table2 FROM dual;

WITH combined AS
(
    SELECT employee_id, hire_date
      FROM TABLE(table1)
    UNION
    SELECT employee_id, hire_date
      FROM TABLE(table2)
)
SELECT CAST(MULTISET
(
    SELECT * FROM combined
) AS EMPLOYEE_TABLE)
INTO return_table FROM dual;

RETURN return_table;

END TEST_FUNCTION2;





SELECT * FROM TABLE (TEST_FUNCTION()); -- Throws exception ORA-03113.

SELECT * FROM TABLE (TEST_FUNCTION2()); -- Works
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using the `CAST( MULTISET` syntax and selecting from dual rather than doing the (seemingly more straightforward) `BULK COLLECT` operation?  And then doing a `MULTISET UNION` in PL/SQL rather than passing the collections back to the SQL engine just to get the data back into PL/SQL?

Comment: @jonearles: I checked DBA_ALERT_HISTORY and did not see any messages. Will check with Oracle.

Comment: @Justin: I tried Bulk Collect into table1 and table2 (without cast), and then replacing UNION with MULTISET UNION, and still get same exception. Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: +1 for contacting support if your workaround isn't suitable. your bug seems to match a registered bug "Bug 14173524 : QUERY WITH UNION INSIDE THE CAST(MULTISET()) CRASHE WITH ORA-07445[QCSTDA()]" / "Bug 8560880 : PL/SQL CODE BLOCK CAUSING ORA-07445 QCSFSQACN"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your particular example but this is a known bug in Oracle version 11.2.0.1.0
It has something to do with the level of nested queries in an expression. I have faced similar error and the same query runs fine in 11.2.0.2.0 (11gR2 patchset 2 I believe).

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9996243